# error C2248 when using a CObject-derived class as CList's type parameter

Tags: mfc, operator-overloading, clist

Let's suppose that I have the following classes declared in my MFC project:

```
class CProfession : public CObject
{
public:
    CProfession();
    virtual ~CProfession();

    int ID;
    CString name;
};

class CPerson : public CObject
{
public:
    CPerson();
    virtual ~CPerson();

    int ID;
    CString name;
    int age;
    CString email;
    CList<CProfession, CProfession&> profession;
};
```

Due to the `CList` declaration (as it was shown right above), I get the following error:
*error C2248: 'CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'*.

I've already tried to implement many kinds of overloadings and copy constructors, but I didn't had any success. I realize that there are other possibilities for solving this error, such as using pointers, but I really looking for a solution that fits exactly in the code that I provided. Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Since `operator=(const CObject&)` is declared private in the base class you have to provide a public assignment operator in your derived class:

```
CProfession& operator=( const CProfession& other ) {
    this->ID = other.ID;
    this->name = other.name;
    return *this;
}
```

Depending on the semantics you want to implement you may have to adjust the implementation to your requirements.

Also keep in mind the [Rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), a rule of thumb claiming that if a class defines one of the following it should probably define all three:

- destructor
- copy constructor
- copy assignment oprator

All of the above are implicitly implemented by the compiler unless they are declared by the programmer. The rationale of the Rule of three is that if one of the compiler-generated member functions does not fit the needs of a class and has to be defined by the programmer, then the others will probably not fit either.

Comment: Thanks! Should I implement the code you've provided in the CProfession.h or .cpp?

Comment: @Mudkip There is no difference as far as the functionality is concerned. It is usually advisable to keep the class definition and implementation separated, i.e. declare the assignment operator in the header file and implement it in the respective .cpp file.

Comment: Alright. Should I use `return *this` in the end of the method?

Comment: @Mudkip Yes, you have to. I updated the code above, sorry about that.

Comment: @llnspectable I've done everything that you've said, but I'm still having the same error. Interestingly, when I click on the error message, I'm redirected to the `CList` declaration scope. Also, when I comment everything related to the `CList` located in the `CPerson` class, the error disappears. In my opinion, these 2 facts leads to the conclusion that the problem resides on the `CList` itself. Do you think that I should try to do some `CList` overloading in the `CPerson` scope? Are there other solutions that may solve this problems?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @llnspectable Just disregard my last post. I gave up of trying to use the `CList` and started to use the `vector<CProfession>` instead. Thank you for all the support you gave!

Comment: @Mudkip Thinking this through again, the error you are getting after providing an assignment operator for `CProfession` might be due to `CPerson` not providing an assignment operator. Regardless of that, unless you **have to** use the MFC collection classes you are probably best advised to go with the C++ container classes instead. I would recommend `list<CProfession>` though, unless you require to have the sequence stored in a single contiguous block of memory.